# Is it possible to couple Tx signal to RTL-SDR Rx signal for a FMCW radar?

Tags: radar, sdr

[image: AFE for FMCW radar. Gromek, D., Samczyński, P., Wielgo, M., Malanowski, M., & Kulpa, K. (2016). Design and validation tests for compact FMCW C-band Analog-Front-End for radar imaging applications. International Journal of Microwave and Wireless Technologies, 8(6), 845-854. doi:10.1017/S1759078716000623]

Above one can see a typical (AFE) diagram for a FMCW. Other block diagrams I found include the processing blocks and and so on as well, but my question rests on the following: can I mix the TX and RX signal BEFORE the BPF and the LNA? I understand that the TX signal will likely be much more powerful (and possibly drown out the RX) than the RX, so are there any ways to mitigate that? Maybe instead of an amp put an attenuator?

I'm trying to implement a FMCW with a separate TX device and use an RTL-SDR for the RX device; however, the SDR already contains an analog-front-end IC. I haven't had much luck finding someone who has already done that with an RTL-SDR specifically. Maybe a TX/RX switch would work?

Comment: Without a bandpass filter in front of the mixer you might get strange images. It also depends on your mixer, commonly a bleed from the tx cavity to the rx cavity forms a mixer. If you can bandpass filter in the sdr, then you might be able to achieve acceptable results.

Comment: @Kartman thank you for your response! I was actually thinking about the scenario where there is another mixer with a coupler put into right on the far right of the schematic, before the box encloses the whole AFE subsystem. And that is then fed into the LNA and the BPF and again thru a BPF (HPF + LPF) and amp and to IF. The coupler and the mixer in the middle wouldn't be present in my case. Making a BPF in the SDR should be possible. Guess I just have to try and see...